# 14.04 upgrade not appearing on update manager

Tags: upgrade

I have 12.04 lts with all software up to date and "notify me of new long term support versions" selected on settings, but there's no mention of 14.04. "There are no updates to install" is the persistent message. I have tried both the main server and the uk one, but to no avail. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
First things first: make sure that you are fully up-to-date. Double check by opening the Update Manager application from the dash and installing all updates listed.

When that’s done, open the Dash again and launch the Terminal application. When it opens click inside the window and type the following command carefully:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Hit the return/enter key and, if prompted, enter your user password.

The Update Manager application will open after a few seconds with a prompt to upgrade. Click this button to begin the process."

Source http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04